# SQLite UPDATE Memory Usage

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am attempting to use a simple SQLite database within an embedded C++ application on Linux. I have the database functionally working, however when I try to update a record within a table I seem to get strange memory usage problems. When running this code the available memory drops in a seemingly erratic way. I would post a plot but I do not have enough reputation.

```
sqlite3 *db;

void UpdateValue(int TlmID, std::string Value)
{
     int rc;
     char *zErrMsg = 0;

     string sqlCommand = "UPDATE tlm SET t_val=\"" + Value + "\", t_time=strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f') where t_id=" + to_string(TlmID) + ";";

     rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlCommand.c_str(), NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);

     if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
     {
          #if DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUG_LEVEL_1
          cout<<"Error: "<<zErrMsg<<endl;
          #endif
          sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
     }
     else
     {
          #if DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUG_LEVEL_2
          cout<<"Successfully updated tlm id "<<TlmID<<endl;
          #endif
     }
}
```

However, if I comment out the sqlite3_exec command, the memory free stays rock solid. This leads me to think I am using the sqlite3_exec command incorrectly. Additionally, I tried closing and opening the database before and after each sqlite3_exec call, but it had no effect.

I have used sqlite3_status() to check SQLITE_STATUS_MEMORY_USED, but the values did not change as the program executed.

I am opening the database connection with:

```
 rc = sqlite3_open(DatabaseName.c_str(), &db);
```

What am I doing that would cause erratic memory consumption by this code? Thank you very much for any help.

---

UPDATE: I am using SQLite Version 3.6.2, which might be the problem, because it is so old.

UPDATE: After updating to 3.8.1 the problem still exists.

---

I measured memory usage before and after each `exec` command and got some interesting results. Approximately every fourth `exec` command 61440 bytes are being consumed and not freed. All the other times, the same amount of memory is free before and after the command.

Comment: Which SQLite version? How much memory do you lose per `exec` call?

Comment: You might [want to configure it](http://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html)